# Does PHP script Stay alive after it is invoked using cURL?

Tags: php, curl

Consider the Situation, I have huge data to process, which i actually want to break into parts, So using CronJobs I invoke a script which checks if any new data to be processed is available, if it is then, the script invokes few other scripts using cURL, the question is,

The script might take a couple of minutes to execute, hence if the invoking parent dies after assigning the jobs to individual scripts before the Individual scripts, then will the indiviual scripts too die ?,

All i have to do to invoke the script is pass a key to the script as a get request and the output of the script is stored in the database itself.

PS: Script refers to PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a command in the background without waiting for a response using ["&"](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/) command

for example
suppose i want to run job.php from index.php without waiting for a response. so in my index.php
instead writing

```
shell_exec('php job.php');
```

i will do

```
shell_exec('php job.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

and it puts the command in the background and free up your terminal immediately.